# Random generated number from python is saying it does not equal in website input, even though when printed on console it says they are the same

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
@main.route("/confirm", methods=['GET', 'POST'])       
def confirm_num():
  print(secure_random)
    if request.method == "POST":
      num_confirm = request.form.get('confirm_number')

      print(num_confirm)
      if num_confirm == secure_random:
        render_template('login.html')
      elif num_confirm != secure_random:
        return 'incorrect code'
    return render_template('confirm.html')
@main.route("/forgot", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def forgot_pass():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    msg = Message('Hello', sender = 
    'noreply@easygadgetsnz.com', recipients = 
    ['jacobptak2005@gmail.com'])
    global secure_random
    secure_random = random.randint(1000, 10000)
    msg.body = """Hi there! Looks like you forgot your password.
    The code you need to login is {}
    """.format(secure_random)
    mail.send(msg)
    return redirect(url_for('main.confirm_num'))

  return render_template('forgot.html')
```

This is only some of the code, I can sucessfully get an email sent to me with a random number. This code that is above shows harvesting the input from the website and comparing it with the variable that contains the random number. It keeps saying `num_confirm != to secure_random`. I tried testing it out by printing both the values on console and they are the same number but still saying they don't equal each other.

Comment: Is `num_confirm` a string?

Comment: Did you `print(num_confirm)` or `print(repr(num_confirm))` ? The latter will probably give you more insight into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a matter of cast? Str compared to Int?

```
int(num_confirm) != int(to secure_random)
```